# Excel, conditionally format based on two columns being equal

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have some data like following

```
325 5   17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 16-JUL-17 08.00.00.000000000 PM 0   -1  74
325 5   17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 16-JUL-17 08.00.00.000000000 PM 0   0   1
325 5   17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 0   -23 26
325 5   17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 0   -22 15
325 5   17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 0   -21 27
325 5   17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 0   -20 11
325 5   17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 0   -4  473
325 5   17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 18-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 0   -23 10
325 5   17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 18-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 0   -22 5
```

I want to conditionally format based on the two date time columns being different. I tried to create a conditional formatting rule like `=exact(C2,D2)` but doesn't work. Also what I want to do is `notExact`. How can I achieve this in Excel?

Comment: Try `=$C2<>$D2`?

Comment: @ScottCraner doesn't work. Doesn't mark `17-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM 18-JUL-17 07.30.00.000000000 AM` for example.

Comment: @ScottCraner when I changed to =$C1<>$D1 it worked. So probably there was some offset problem. You can write the answer and I will accept it. Thanks!